# how to change values between loop

Tags: php

I extracted the values of the array on the foreach loop, but I want when it retrieves a certain `'br_title'` changed href link to `<a href="http://noorresults.moe.sa`..how to do that with simple code?..

```
          <ul class="riMenu">
            <?php foreach ($last_branches as $last) { ?>
          <li><a href="<?= base_url(); ?>branches/show/<?php if (!empty($last['br_id'])) echo $last['br_id'] ?>"> <?php if (!empty($last['br_title'])) echo $last['br_title'] ?></a></li>

    <?php }; ?>
        </ul>


    </div>
</div><!-- Menu E
```

Comment: Are the values known of the `br_title` what you expect? For example is it static in which you can compare `if($last['br_title'] == "some_title)` etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code as below

```
<?php 

$total_to_show = 5; // take offset
$count = 1; //counter until it reach to offset

foreach ($last_branches as $last) { if($count > $total_to_show){?>


                <li><a href="http://noorresults.moe.sa/MarksInquiry/StudentMark.aspx"> <?php  if(!empty($last['br_title'])) echo $last['br_title'] ?></a></li>
                <? }else{?>
                <li><a href="<?= base_url(); ?>branches/show/<?php  if(!empty($last['br_id'])) echo $last['br_id'] ?>"> <?php  if(!empty($last['br_title'])) echo $last['br_title'] ?></a></li>
                <?php } 
$count++;
} ?>
```